# Считать из файла арифметическое выражение, распарсить его, решить и записать ответ в тот же файл

Tags: java, математика

При решении воспользовался ОПЗ. 
Вот мой код:

```
public static double eval(String inputString) {
LinkedList<Double> st = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<Character> op = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    char character = inputString.charAt(i);
    if (isDelim(character))
        continue;
    if (character == '(')
        op.add('(');
    else if (character == ')') {
        while (op.getLast() != '(')
            processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
        op.removeLast();
    } else if (isOperator(character)) {
        while (!op.isEmpty() && priority(op.getLast()) >= priority(character))
            processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
        op.add(character);
    } else {
        String operand = "";
        while (i < inputString.length() && Character.isDigit(inputString.charAt(i)))
            operand += inputString.charAt(i++);
        --i;
        st.add(Double.parseDouble(operand));
    }
}
while (!op.isEmpty())
    processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
return st.get(0);
```

}

Есть проблема с таким типом -(89+100), -3 + 2. Т.е. когда минус унарный. Не подскажите, как лучше это обыграть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если встречаешь унарный минус, то вычитай из нуля, то есть нужно слева от минуса добавить 0 в твоем случае будет не -(89+100), -3+2, а 0-(89+100), 0-3+2. А куда добавить реши сам, либо до того как парсишь строку расставляй нули, либо в процессе.